# Access delegate from static subproject

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have included a static subproject in the main one. Subproject has a couple of delegates that I need to call from the main one, but I can't. I have tried @class,#import, but still not accessible from the main project. Delegates are well implemented, because I have tried to use it in another class from the subproject and it works well.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you add to **HEADER_SEARCH_PATH** paths to all nessessary headers in XCode build settings? I think subproject can work as a dependency, but it is not automaticaly adds all headers to the main project.

Answer (score 1):

you should update following parameters in your main project target-> build settings:

```
USER_HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS
LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS
HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS
```